# Would it be possible to extract/filter out two waves of different power but same frequency?

Tags: frequency, power

If we can use say Fourier Transform to extract every individual frequency on a signal, can we do the same for power?

I was figuring if it would be possible to extract them for further inspection on how the signal is being interfered constructively/destructively.

Edit: Sorry it's my first time here, do let me know if there is any issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about the case where a weak signal is being interfered with by a stronger signal of similar frequency.

If the spectrum of an interfering source overlaps with the spectrum of the source of interest, then the two can not be separated completely. There is an exception to this if the two signals are orthogonal to each other (i.e. they have a 90 degree phase difference at every frequency), but that is rarely the case. How much the interfering signal can be suppressed with signal processing methods depends on the details of the signal and the spectrum of the interfering signal. You can find entire textbooks on this subject in the digital information transmission literature. There is no simple, satisfying answer that covers the topic in general. In many cases we simply have to live with the interfering signal. This is especially the case with white noise.